# Android Studio problem facing with aapt error

Tags: android

how to find any specific mistakes in my android project that causing AAPT2 error because it just says "check log for details" and though i am not getting anything there....please help Thanks in Advance

Comment: It means check your Event log, not your logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Aapt error is caused due to an error in attribute in XML files. Click on build tab and click on sync in the top pane of build window.

Answer (score -1):

Just click LOGCAT
And there you'll see the log

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
Try with the below techniques 
firstlly cross check your code may be you have hard coded some thing then try these techniques.

 1- open terminal and type gradlew clean and press enter key.
Second method.
 2- go to build and click on click on clean project and rebulid.

third method
3- go to gradle.properties
   android.enableAapt2=false
```